# Symfony Form Transformer on CheckboxType: String to Bool

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a symfony4 form that has a `CheckboxType` and submitted with string values (`'0'` or `'1'`). Now, I want to convert them to booleans. When getting the data (view transform), a boolean value should be returned. I have followed [this guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#about-model-and-view-transformers).

```
$builder->add('box', CheckboxType::class, [
    'required' => false,
])
$builder->get('box')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer([$this, 'modelTransform'], [$this, 'modelReverseTransform']));
$builder->get('box')->addViewTransformer(new CallbackTransformer([$this, 'viewTransform'], [$this, 'viewReverseTransform']));
```

I tried the following functions, but then, the `box` value is not even included in the output.

```
// view reverse transform
public function viewReverseTransform($string)
{
    var_dump('viewReverseTransform', $string);
    return $string === '1';
}

// view transform -> output
public function viewTransform($bool)
{
    var_dump('viewTransform', $bool);
    return $bool;
    //return $bool === true ? '1' : '0';
}

// model reverse transform
public function modelReverseTransform($bool) {
    var_dump('modelReverseTransform', $bool);
    return $bool;
}

// model transform
public function modelTransform($bool) {
    var_dump('modelTransform', $bool);
    return $bool;
}
```

I tried also some other casting, but it doesn't map the values correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that I first have to reset via `$builder->get('box')->resetViewTransformers()`. Then it works.

Comment: Thank you it helped me, I had also the same issue.